# How to shift values in a data frame according the a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, random

Consider the following data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

characteristics = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
N = int(1e5)
random_characteristics = [random.choice(characteristics) for i in range(N)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'character': random_characteristics})

df

--------------------------------------------------------------------
       character
0          A
1          G
2          E
3          G
4          D
...        ...
99995      E
99996      G
99997      A
99998      D
99999      B

100000 rows × 1 columns
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, my goal is to create a new column `characteristics_shifted` that is shifted according to the list `characteristics`, where the number of shifts can be specified by the user.
For instance, if you specify `shift = 1`, then each character is shifted by one. If the character equals `H`, then it cannot be shifted by one and therefore remains the same. If `shift = 2` and the character equals `B`, then I want to get `D`. If, in turn, the character equals `G`, I want to get `H`. The same holds for negative shifts, but in the other direction.

Example:

```py
character  characteristics_shifted (shift=1)  characteristics_shifted (shift=-2)  

A          B                                  A
G          H                                  F
E          F                                  D
G          H                                  F
D          E                                  C
H          H                                  F
H          H                                  F
A          B                                  A
E          F                                  D
C          D                                  B
F          G                                  E
```

Note: My data frame contains around 21 mio. rows. It does not contain nan values.

Comment: Using letters as ordered categories for basic math operations will make the solution more complicated and much slower.

Comment: for a shift of 1, A becomes B, what about H? Is is A or NaN?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, yeah, but that's the data frame I have. I could also map a new column consisting of integers and operate over it, but the logic would be the same, wouldn't it?

Comment: The operation (add, min and max) are common for numeric types and have to be mimicked for letters. The problem is the performance. However, using categorical data is surprisingly fast [ [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TFwQy8PKFUczIDxBEK0dmOMHVm1Xm69Z?usp=sharing) ].

Comment: Yes, working with Categorical speeds up many operations (and uses much less memory!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a Series and use `map` on the shifted Series:

```
c = pd.Series(characteristics, index=characteristics)

shifts = [1, -2]

for s in shifts:
    df[f'shift={s}'] = df['character'].map(c.shift(-s).ffill().bfill())
    
print(df)
```

output:

```
      character shift=1 shift=-2
0             G       H        E
1             G       H        E
2             A       B        A
3             E       F        C
4             H       H        F
...         ...     ...      ...
99995         G       H        E
99996         E       F        C
99997         E       F        C
99998         C       D        A
99999         D       E        B

[100000 rows x 3 columns]
```

###### optimization

if there are many columns, this variant will be faster (thanks @MichaelSzczesny for pointing this out!):

```
cat = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(df['character']))
c = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(characteristics), index=characteristics)

shifts = [1, -2]

for s in shifts:
    df[f'shift={s}'] = cat.map(c.shift(-s).ffill().bfill())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper function to shift the characters, using `min` and `max` to prevent the index going past the limits of the `characteristics` array. You can then `apply` that to the `character` column:

```py
def shift(char, shift):
    idx = max(min(characteristics.index(char) + shift, len(characteristics)-1), 0)
    return characteristics[idx]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'character': characteristics})
shifts = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
for s in shifts:
    df[f'shift={s}'] = df['character'].apply(lambda c:shift(c, s))
```

Output:

```
  character shift=-2 shift=-1 shift=0 shift=1 shift=2
0         A        A        A       A       B       C
1         B        A        A       B       C       D
2         C        A        B       C       D       E
3         D        B        C       D       E       F
4         E        C        D       E       F       G
5         F        D        E       F       G       H
6         G        E        F       G       H       H
7         H        F        G       H       H       H
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

characteristics = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
N = int(1e5)
random_characteristics = [random.choice(characteristics) for i in range(N)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'character': random_characteristics})

df['shifted'] = [str(chr(ord(i)+1)) for i in df['character']] #+1 shift 1 position
print(df)
```

Comment: If you shift by `-1`, then you get '@' values for 'A'. If you specify '+3', you also get values beyond the list. In addition to that, the list `characteristics` tells you the order. So, if I change my list to `['A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'K', 'G', 'H']`, then your approach is not applicable anymore. It was just by accident that the list is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Actually, this is based on their requirements. Not for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Although @mozway's approach is very simple and efficient, I would like to add my solution as well. I think my solution is better in terms of performance, but does include more lines of code.

```py
def _get_index_positions(vector_to_shift: np.ndarray, arr_characteristics: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Get index position of matches."""
    # Get sorted index of characteristics
    sort_idx = arr_characteristics.argsort()
    # Find index position of matches
    return sort_idx[np.searchsorted(arr_characteristics, vector_to_shift, sorter=sort_idx)]

def shift(target: np.ndarray, shift: int, index_matches: np.ndarray):
    """Shifts and clips index."""
    shifted_index = np.clip(index_matches + shift, 0, len(target) - 1)
    return target[shifted_index]

# Define characteristics as array
arr_characteristics = np.array(characteristics)

index = _get_index_positions(df.character.values, arr_characteristics)


shifts = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -3, -4]
for s in shifts:
    df[f'shift={s}'] = shift(arr_characteristics, s, index)
```

I would mainly rely on `numpy` and use indexing to achieve that. My approach takes around `10 seconds`, while @mozway's approach takes around `14` seconds for a 21 Mio row data frame.

##### Edit

The optimized version of @mozway's approach only takes around `3.5 seconds` on my machine for 21 mio rows. Now, his approach is definitely better in every dimension.